# How to remove "unmet peer dependency " warning?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

While running yarn install command I am getting this warning

```
warning "react-scripts > eslint-config-react-app > eslint-plugin-flowtype@8.0.3" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/plugin-syntax-flow@^7.14.5".
warning "react-scripts > eslint-config-react-app > eslint-plugin-flowtype@8.0.3" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx@^7.14.9".
warning " > eslint-config-airbnb@19.0.4" has unmet peer dependency "eslint-plugin-import@^2.25.3".
warning " > eslint-config-airbnb@19.0.4" has unmet peer dependency "eslint-plugin-react-hooks@^4.3.0".
warning "eslint-config-airbnb > eslint-config-airbnb-base@15.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "eslint-plugin-import@^2.25.2".warning " > eslint-config-airbnb-typescript@17.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "eslint-plugin-import@^2.25.3".
warning "stylelint-config-standard-scss > stylelint-config-recommended-scss > postcss-scss@4.0.5" has unmet peer dependency "postcss@^8.3.3".
```

Thanks in adavance

Comment: If I delete yarn.lock and again installed then also same problem persists

Comment: have you tried installing said unmet peer dependencies? The warnings are there for a reason

Comment: all those dependencies are there but which is having diffrent version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a resolution in package.json file

```
"resolution":
    {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx":"^7.14.9",
    "eslint-plugin-import":"^2.25.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks":"^4.3.0",
    "postcss":"^8.3.3",
    }
```